# How to enable apt install in Bitnami containers?

Tags: docker, bitnami

I'm running a Bitnami/pytorch container and would like to install packages using apt. However I cannot do it as `sudo` is not installed. For example:

```sh
$ sudo apt install nano
bash: sudo: command not found
```

So what is the preferred way of getting `apt install` to work?

Comment: Can you connect to the container as root? With docker exec --user root -it container-name.

Comment: Where/when is `apt install nano` executed? At container build time or at container start time? At container build time, we can change the current user to `USER root` in order to execute commands that require root access and switch back to the non-root user afterwards (`USER 1001`).

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. I'm able connect as root and that solves the problem.